# "Aera" of square if "aera" of circle is passage in upper decimal

Tags: geometry, circles, pi

A circle with a radius of $5$ has an *aera* of $50$. What will be the *aera* of the square with a width of $10=2\times 5$? Do we need a ratio of diagonal/width to find this?

Answer (score 2):

A circle with a radius of $5$ has an area of $25\pi$, and this corresponds to an *aera* of $50$. A square with a width of $10$ has an area of $100$, and this corresponds to an *aera* of $\frac{50}{25\pi}\times 100=\frac{200}{\pi}$.

Comment: Area of square / Aera of circle = $4/\pi$=1.2732 .


The square onto the circle of radius 5 have an aera of $50=7,071²$ .

$7,071 / 5$ is root of 2 and not 1,2732.